# Can we use quantization techniques to train ML models from scratch?

Tags: training, fine-tuning, accelerators

I'm currently learning about quantization and have seen that most methods for quantizing are for a Post-Training conversion or, in some cases, for efficient finetuning like the QLORA method. I'd like to know to what extent hard quantization techniques (4bit, 2bit) are usable or even theoretically useful for training models from the ground up. I know that half-way precision techniques (16-bit)  are used on mixed precisions for Nvidia Tensor Cores leveraging  3x [speedups on computations](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/performance/mixed-precision-training/index.html), but has been tried yet to use lower bits precisions on SOTA hardware with good results? In a way, I'm also asking if the question has something to do with the latest [BitNet b1.58](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2402.17764.pdf) model that, currently, I don't understand that well.